# Alchemy on 1.05 patch

Tags: the-witcher-3

Since 1.05, I can't make twice an alchemy recipe.
Including mutagens and alcohol.

Do you people face the same issue or know how to make multiples upgraded mutagens ?

Comment: Oh I found a workaround by myself, just drop the item you want to craft, it'll allow you to craft a second one. Then just pick up the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is fixed as of June 15th, 2015 ([Hotfix 1.06](http://thewitcher.com/news/view/1064)). It was a widespread issue before this.

Answer (score 0):

You can make more than one Mutagen once you have the required materials, confirmed on PC. White Gull, on the other hand, does not appear to be mass producible after 1.05 short of dropping each one before making another.

EDIT: I'm certain it let me make a second Red Mutagen post patch. Currently trying to find enough lesser red mutagen to try it again. Green and blue do not work.

Comment: just checked, still can't. Maybe i don't have the last patch (on PC too)

Comment: Hrm. I'm sure it allowed me to do it with Red Mutagen, but I don't have enough lesser to test it. Green and blue don't work though, you're right about that.

Comment: Maybe the one you crafted was the first one of his kind